# Dimple X-Y Chart without Aggregation

Tags: charts, dimple.js

Using Dimple, I would like to create a simple line chart with numeric X-Y data points. I use addMeasureAxis() for Y axis. If I use addCategoryAxis() for X, I get a data point for each X value if all X are unique, else dimple will aggregate for like values of X. If I use addMeasureAxis(), again, Dimple will aggregate, this time by summing. If I modify the X values to be time (hh:mm) and use addTimeAxis(), dimple will treat each X value as a time, and will place the data points properly. Is there a way to create a similar chart with numeric X values of arbitrary scale? I'm not sure, but I may be asking if Dimple can create charts with no aggregation on the X values.

The code for an X-Y line chart with time values on X axis is shown below. Note that the time values are not equally spaced. Dimple correctly positions the X-Y points.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
    var data = [
      { "xval":"12:00", "yval":20 },
      { "xval":"13:00", "yval":30 },
      { "xval":"14:00", "yval":25 },
      { "xval":"16:00", "yval":50 }
    ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addTimeAxis("x", "xval", "%H:%M", "%H:%M" );
    chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "yval");
    chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    chart.draw();
  </script>
```

Here is similar code with "xval" being numeric, which results in 4 data points, but without the desired spacing between X values 14 and 16.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
    var data = [
      { "xval":12, "yval":20 },
      { "xval":13, "yval":30 },
      { "xval":14, "yval":25 },
      { "xval":16, "yval":50 }
    ];
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "xval" );
    chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "yval");
    chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    chart.draw();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll need to add a key dimension and a grouping dimension into your data and draw the line like this:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
var data = [
  { "key": 1, "group": "a", "xval":12, "yval":20 },
  { "key": 2, "group": "a", "xval":13, "yval":30 },
  { "key": 3, "group": "a", "xval":14, "yval":25 },
  { "key": 4, "group": "a", "xval":16, "yval":50 }
];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "xval" );
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "yval");
chart.addSeries(["key", "group"], dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();
```

Version 2 of dimple will remove the need for the group column so you'll be able to do this instead to achieve exactly the same result, but I'm afraid the key is still required:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
var data = [
  { "key": 1, "xval":12, "yval":20 },
  { "key": 2, "xval":13, "yval":30 },
  { "key": 3, "xval":14, "yval":25 },
  { "key": 4, "xval":16, "yval":50 }
];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "xval" );
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "yval");
chart.addSeries(["key", "a"], dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();
```

If you know that x or y values will be unique in your dataset then you could use one of those as a key.  So for example if x values will be unique, the following will work in version 2:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
var data = [
  { "xval":12, "yval":20 },
  { "xval":13, "yval":30 },
  { "xval":14, "yval":25 },
  { "xval":16, "yval":50 }
];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "xval" );
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "yval");
chart.addSeries(["xval", "a"], dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks, John. Dimple is great. Adding a uniquely-valued field as required for v2 will be fine, and I see it will be available soon. One follow-up question: have you considered supporting date/time values in unix time (integer) and/or julian day (float) format?

Comment: Dimple supports something very close to Unix Time.  Milliseconds since epoch (whereas I think Unix Time is usually Seconds since epoch) is supported if you pass null to the input format parameter.  I have to say I've never had cause to work with Julian time however I imagine it will be a fairly simple conversion to turn Julian time to Unix Time.

Comment: Milliseconds since epoch is great. I have used Julian day rather than Unix time when I need sub-second resolution, but I prefer integers, and the conversion is simple. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi John. I tried passing null to the input format parameter of addTimeAxis(), and it seems to not quite work. In some cases, I would get so many axis ticks that the data was unreadable, in other cases I would get none. If you have an example of how to use this feature, please let me know. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Are you using chart.addTimeAxis (https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addTimeAxis)?  It sounds like you are using a category axis, which will draw a point for every distinct value.

Comment: I am using addTimeAxis(), and I only see this behavior when using null as the input format argument. If you want to see this code, should I create a new question?

Comment: Yeah, it might help. Here's an example of epoch time on an axis, maybe it will help: http://dimplejs.org/adhoc_viewer.html?id=adhoc_bar_scroll

Comment: Thanks for the example. Things get weird on the X axis if the time values are very small, e.g. under 10000, but it works pretty well as long as they are larger. With very small values, all points are displayed as one.

Comment: It's because the list of d3 time intervals doesn't include milliseconds.  You can do seconds but that's as granular as it gets.  Here's a simple example of using seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/bhzUw/1/

Comment: Got it. Have you written something about Dimple version 2? I've searched, but haven't found any notes on what is changed or new.

Comment: Sure , it's all in the release notes: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/releases

Comment: My workaround for this (if loading numbers from a CSV file, for example) is a simple loop to add the key to each existing data object after the data has been loaded in - e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/5uKqn/